# Peticiones no entrar en el @RequestMapping pertienente en Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Estoy practicando una aplicacion en Spring y estoy teniendo un problema que no soy capaz  de comprender.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @RequestMapping(path="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("login");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/api_endpoint/login",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public UserApiResponse loginUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        UserApiResponse userApiResponse=new UserApiResponse();
        User userExists = userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (userExists == null) {
            userApiResponse.setMessageError("There is not any user with the email provided");
            userApiResponse.setHttpCode(400);
        }else if(!bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(user.getPassword(), userExists.getPassword())){
            userApiResponse.setMessageError("Incorrect password");
            userApiResponse.setHttpCode(401);
        }else{
            userApiResponse.setHttpCode(200);
        }

        return userApiResponse;
    }


    @RequestMapping(path="/registration",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView registration(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        User user = new User(); 
        modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
        modelAndView.setViewName("registration");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/registration",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView createNewUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        User userExists = userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (userExists != null) {
            bindingResult
                    .rejectValue("email", "error.user",
                            "There is already a user registered with the email provided");
        }
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            modelAndView.setViewName("registration");
        } else {
            userService.saveUser(user);
            modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "User has been registered successfully");
            modelAndView.addObject("user", new User());
            modelAndView.setViewName("registration");

        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Tengo estos `@RequestMapping`, pero da igual el `path` que pongo en la request desde el cliente, que siempre me entra en el primer `@RequestMapping`, el de `login`. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Tienes habilitado `spring-security`? Cuando entras con un usuario anónimo y no tienes definido un path sin seguridad siempre te va a mandar al login.

Comment: Buenas @Angel, si, esta habilitado, pero he visto que no tenia agregado el path de /api_endpoint a la configuración así que entiendo que agregándolo me funcionara. Formulalo en forma de respuesta y te lo acepto. Que me has dado la clave para verlo ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando entras con un usuario anónimo y no tienes definido un path sin seguridad siempre te va a mandar al `login`.

---

Falta definir el path de `/api_endpoint` a la configuración.